# Responder Perguntas com finalidades obscuras

Tags: debate, comportamento

A programação assim como qualquer outro conhecimento pode ser usada para fazer coisas ilegais como por exemplo

- Acesso a site de terceiros para extração de dados ilegalmente
- Criptografar provas
- Capturar dados ilegalmente (keylogger)
- Ferramentas ou até mesmo utilização de exploit com objetivos ilegais

Algumas perguntas fica explicito o objetivo obscuro, mas tão explicito que não da vontade de ajudar, isso separa esse debate em 2 seguimentos, Devemos Banir esse tipo de pergunta ?(se ainda não existir alguma regra especifica para isso), ou devemos usar nosso Critério individual para ajudar ou não.

Comment: putz, acho valido colocar mais palavras chaves, pesquisei algumas keywords e não encontrei.

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes o voto de fechar como duplicata tem esta função também. A pergunta é marcada como duplicata, mas ela continua "pesquisável", e apontará para a anterior.

Comment: Ah sim, pensei que perguntas sinalizadas eram apagadas em tempos em tempos

Comment: @IsvaldoFernandes A maioria delas é mesmo, mas duplicatas são diferentes. No MSE mostra [os critérios específicos](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/177950), note que as duplicatas só são removidas se elas têm mais votos negativos que positivos, ou pouquíssimas visualizações (i.e. se a duplicata está ajudando as pessoas a encontrar informação, ela é mantida indefinidamente, se não está, então é apagada).